# How to subtract and amplify signals

Tags: amplifier

How do I draw a circuit diagram that subtracts two inputs signals and then amplifies the subtracted signal by a factor of 839?

Comment: The kind of circuit you're looking for is a *differential amplifier*. There are a number of ways to achieve this.

Comment: Beware of what you ask here, you may get the *exact answer* to it, which may not the one you wanted.

Comment: Do you require a functional circuit to perform the task you have described or do you want to know how to draw a circuit diagram?

Answer (score 4):

One approach is to use an [instrumentation amplifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instrumentation_amplifier). 
[image]

[image]

If, say, you set R2, R3 = 10.0K and R1 = 100K then 
Rgain = 238.7 ohms

There are some advantages of this over a single-amplifier differential amplifier and some disadvantages (such as requiring two more op-amps). The best choice will depend on requirements such as the required common mode range and common mode rejection ratio.

Edit: Scott S. raised the point of CMRR.. to illustrate the improvement from having the gain ahead of elimination of the common mode voltage, I'll show two simulations. Both are with LM324s (because they're crummy) and mathematically perfect resistors (100K + 119.35 ohms for the diff amp and as mentioned above for the in amp). +/-15V supplies, differential signal is 1mV/50Hz. In both, the red trace is the instrumentation amplifier output and the green trace is the simple differential amplifier output.

Output:

[image]

The improvement in offset of 160mV for the in amp is not real, it's because the offset is matched between the op-amps, and this will not be expected. But you can see the outputs are very similar.

Now add a common mode voltage of 8V with 3V @200Hz superimposed:

[image]

The common mode AC and DC offset both show up in the diff amp and are not visible in the in amp configuration.

It's important to realize that the sensitivity of CMRR to **resistor matching** in the in-amp configuration is almost 3 orders of magnitude improved over a simple differential amplifier. That's because very substantial gain occurs before the common-mode signal is subtracted. In the degenerate case, as Rgain increases to infinity, it's just a couple buffers in front of a differential amplifier and you don't get the improvement.

Comment: Actually, while certainly providing an extra gain stage and equal and high input impedances for the two inputs, building your own instr amp out of op amps does not offer better CMRR than a simple difference amplifier.

Comment: @ScottSeidman I've heard this stated before.. but it's not right (at least in general, for Rgain not open). Because there is gain in the front end the CMRR of the op-amps themselves are reduced by that factor minus one- assuming the two input op-amps have matched CMRR. I'll add a simulation to illustrate this point.

Comment: Do the Sim with 1% resistors and watch the CMRR  die.  It's not the op amps that kill the CMRR, it's mismatched resistors on the last stage.

Comment: It's the mathematically perfect resistors the can't be implemented on the bench anywhere near how well even the cheapest inamp  IC  can have them.  Same for difference amp ICs

Comment: By definition, increasing the gain in the part without common mode problems increases CMRR.  What happens, though, if you have a 0.5% mismatch in R1?

Comment: @ScottSeidman Last time I designed such an amp, I used Vishay metal foil networks that track within 0.1ppm/°C and are ratio matched to 0.01%. 1% resistors are for pull-ups etc. ;-)

Answer (score -2):

This can be done quite easily.  At the very least, you can use pencil on a piece of paper.

Nowadays, there are a lot of computer programs out there for drawing schematics, some of them free.  There is a built-in schematic editor on this site, for example.  Then there are larger programs like Eagle, Kicad, etc, that are either free or have free versions for limited uses.

The advantage of using software for drawing the schematic is that the result is neater (if done right), and can then be used directly for layout and maybe for simulation.  However, it takes some time to learn the software.

To draw any schematic, not just the function you ask for, you have to of course figure out the circuit you want the schematic to represent.  However, that's not what your question is about, so no point elaborating on that.

Comment: -1 for sophistry.

Comment: @EMFi: I'm not surprised you came along and found some excuse to downvote this.  However, your stated reason doesn't makes sense. If you're going to use phancy words, it's a good idea to make sure you are using them correctly.  "Sophistry" means something that sounds right but is actually wrong.  However, what I said actually *is* right, and answers the question that was asked.  If you truly believe this is sophistry, then you should be able to point out which facts I got wrong.

Comment: -1 for childishness. Human language is imprecise. If I ask, "do you have the time?" a 12-year-old might think it's clever to answer, "yes", but an adult tells me what time it is.

Comment: @TheP: And a responsible person teaches that's a bad way to ask for the time.  If we let people get away with asking questions in a annoying way, then they have no reason to stop doing it.  People need to stop and *think* about what they are really asking.  One good way to do that is to answer what they actually ask, and refuse to engage in the same sloppiness they do.  Stupid ways of asking, like *"can you tell me ...?"* need to be countered whenever they occur.

Comment: It's not a bad way to ask for the time. It's an ordinary human way to soften the question to make it more polite and less demanding.

Comment: Man this is an absurd answer. You're that teacher who thinks he's super clever responding "I DON'T KNOW, CAN YOU??! HAHAHAHAHA" when a student politely asks if he can use the restroom.

Comment: @ Olin: You justify your vituperative bullying by pretending that you're extending "tough love", when all you're really doing is exalting yourself at the expense of those poor souls who can't fight back.  You also have your own foibles with the use of written English which you write off as "style", but which reflect flaws in your character which keep you from admitting to error when it's as plain as the nose on your face that you're dead wrong. In short, you're a nasty piece of work who cares little about anything but his own self-aggrandizement.

Comment: @ Olin: It's quite clear that the OP was asking about a differential amplifier followed by a gain stage, but instead of responding to what you _MUST_ have known was the question, you chose to derail the real subject and, instead, change the subject in order to abuse him  with some irrelevant cockamamie drivel instead of getting to the heart of the matter.  Sophistry indeed, with a red herring and a straw man to boot.